# How to fetch dates(as weekly-monthly) from CoreData in swift?

Tags: swift, core-data, uidatepicker

i am trying to make a spending control application. However, I cannot pull storages from the dates registered by users on a weekly or monthly basis.Monthly and weekly extraction of user-selected and saved dates to coredata
how can I do that ?

```
if let newSaglik = Int(saglikText.text!){
            if let newMarket = Int(marketText.text!){
                if let newOther = Int(otherText.text!){
                    toplam = newSaglik + newMarket + newOther
                    
                }
            }
        }
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let newPendings = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Pendings", into: context)
        
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .medium
        formatter.timeStyle = .none
        
        let pickTime = formatter.date(from: dateText.text!)
        
        newPendings.setValue(String(toplam), forKey: "totalPend")
        newPendings.setValue(pickTime, forKey: "selectDate")
        
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch{
            
        }
      
    }
```

````
dateArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
        toplamArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Pendings")
        fetch.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        
        do {
           let results =  try context.fetch(fetch)
            if results.count > 0 {
                for result in results as! [NSManagedObject]{
                    if let getPend = result.value(forKey: "totalPend") as? String{
                        toplamArray.append(getPend)
                    }
                    
                    if let getDate = result.value(forKey: "selectDate") as? Date {
                        dateArray.append(getDate)
                    }
                }
                
                tablevİEW.reloadData()
            }
              
        } catch {
            
        }
        
    }```
````

Comment: You have to apply a predicate with format `"selectDate > @% AND selectDate < %@", date1 as NSDate, date2 as NSDate` where `date1` and `date2` are the start and end dates of the date ranges. And - unrelated - if you specify  `NSFetchRequest< Pendings>` then `results` is `[Pendings]` and you can use type safe dot notation rather than ugly `value(forKey:)`

Comment: Can you show with an example?

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't use multiple arrays (like `toplamArray` and `dateArray`) as data source, use one array of `Pendings` instances.

Second of all take advantage of the generic capabilities of `NSManagedObject`. The major benefit is to have strong typed property values using dot notation rather than error prone KVC syntax `value(forKey:)`. Also insert a new record with `Pendings(context: context)` rather than with the old non-generic syntax.

---

Assuming the significant part of the `Pendings` class is

```
class Pendings : NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var selectDate : Date
    @NSManaged var totalPend : String

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Pendings> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Pendings>(entityName: "Pendings")
    }
}
```

add a function to return a predicate for a given `month`, `year` and `keyPath`

```
func monthlyPredicateFor(month: Int, in year: Int, keyPath: KeyPath<Pendings,Date>) throws -> NSPredicate {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let startComponents = DateComponents(year: year, month: month)
    guard let startDate = calendar.date(from: startComponents) else { throw PredicateError.invalidDate }
    let endDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .month, value: 1, to: startDate)!
    let keyPathString = NSExpression(forKeyPath: keyPath).keyPath
    return NSPredicate(format: "%K > %@ AND %K < %@", argumentArray: [keyPathString, startDate, keyPathString, endDate])
}
```

This requires a custom `Error` enum

```
enum PredicateError: Error {
    case invalidDate
}
```

As mentioned replace the two arrays representing the data source with **one** array for example

```
var filteredPendings = [Pendings]()
```

In the code to fetch the data apply the predicate and assign the result to `filteredPendings`

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
do {
    let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<Pendings> = Pendings.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.predicate = try monthlyPredicateFor(month: 7, in: 2023, keyPath: \.selectDate)
    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    filteredPendings = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    tableview.reloadData()
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

The predicate for the week depends on what `weekly` actually means. A week number or a start date or something else?